# How to use 'having' with 'where' in same select statement.Here, I want to display Total Guest<=10

Tags: database, oracle

```
SQL written by me:

 select distinct resortid,sum(adultcount+childcount)"TOTAL GUEST" 
 from booking 
 having count(1)>=1  
 group by resortid
 order by resortid;
```

Output:

```
  RESORTID   TOTAL GUEST
 ---------- -----------
  1001      11
  1002      10
  1003       2
  1004       2
```

Expected Output:

```
  RESORTID   TOTAL GUEST
 ---------- -----------
  1002      10
  1003       2
  1004       2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the distinct. Change the `having` to do what you want.

```
 select resortid,sum(adultcount+childcount)"TOTAL GUEST" 
 from booking 
 having sum(adultcount+childcount) BETWEEN 1 AND 10   
 group by resortid
 order by resortid;
```